# How to save just one column values of a table into an array?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My query returns something like this:

[image]

I want to save each value into array. I know how to save each column of a row using SELECT INTO, but I don't know how to save rows of a table with just one column.

I would like to get this:

```
my_array(1) = 11111
my_array(2) = 22222
my_array(3) = 33333
....
```

Length of an array is 6. I know that my query will not return more than 6 rows. 
If query returns less than 6 rows is it possible to put NULL into array element where there is no rows for it?

Comment: `bulk collect into`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in a comment you may use `BULK COLLECT`

```
select your_col BULK COLLECT 
 INTO your_collection from my_array where some_condition = 'something';
```

Regarding your question

> if query returns less than 6 rows is it possible to put NULL into
>   array element where there is no rows for it

You have not said why it's required but a `BULK COLLECT` will create as many elements in the array as the number of rows present in the query result. In case you need `NULL` elements, you may use  `count` and `extend` collection methods to check and allocate null elements until the count is 6.

```
DECLARE
TYPE myarrtype is table of integer;
my_array myarrtype;
BEGIN
  select level bulk collect into my_array from dual 
  connect by level <= 4; --generates 4 integers 1-4 and loads into array.
    dbms_output.put_line('OLD COUNT '||my_array.count);

  if my_array.count <= 6 then
     my_array.extend(6 - my_array.count); --This appends required number of 
                                          --NULL elements   
  dbms_output.put_line('NEW COUNT '||my_array.count);
  end if;
END;
/
```

**Output**

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
OLD COUNT 4
NEW COUNT 6
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f92de4e8343346784a8d44e8a20cd391)

Comment: Thank you! Seems like a perfect solution. 
So this works only with table of integer, not varray(6), right? 

I have another varray of 6 elements and I need to find out is there at least one same value that exists both in first and second array using for loop. So I created loop inside another loop: 

  `FOR i IN 1..6 LOOP 
    FOR ii IN 1..6 LOOP 
      IF trisks(i) = orisks(ii) THEN 
        dbms_output.put_line('совпадает по риску ' || trisks(i));
        END IF;
        END LOOP;
        END LOOP;`

Please tell me if I do something wrong.

Comment: @РусланХ : This answers your original question. If you think it works, please accept it. If there are further questions, consider asking a new one with required details.

Comment: I've tried your solution. Changed both arrays to tables and it works the way it should be. Thank you again!